# What does the word あるほうで mean? 「かわいげがあるほうで」

Tags: words

It is bold in the below sentence.

> まあ そんなのはまだまだかわいげが**あるほうで**よ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually three words.

「あるほうで」＝「ある方で」

「～～[方]{ほう}」 means "on the ~~ side", "relatively ~~", etc.

「かわいげがある」 means "charming in an innocent way".

"That is still pretty charming (compared to something else)."