# Meaning of ほうなんで?

Tags: translation, meaning, parsing

It is a "simple" sentence, but I can't find any information how I should parse and interpret this part.

> これでも用心深い**ほうなんで**ね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you already know how to make a comparison using ほう and より in Japanese? If not, please learn it first.

- [Japanese Grammar – Making Comparisons](http://www.punipunijapan.com/yori-hou-ga/)
- [Japanese Comparison: より, …の方が, and …で一番](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-comparison/)

The sentence in question is an extension of this. While there is no explicit comparison target marked with ～より, this ほう still means "comparatively" or "relatively".

> これでも用心深いほうなんでね。
>   Despite my appearance, (if one has to categorize me either as a cautious or as a careless person,) I'm comparatively a cautious person, you know.
>   I'm a more cautious person than I may look, you know.

これでも (literally "even with this") is a set phrase, "although you may think otherwise" or "although I may not look like it".

Similar examples:

> - このケーキは甘いほうだ。 This cake is relatively sweet.
> - 私はよく寝るほうです。 I'm relatively a good sleeper.
> - あまりテレビは見ないほうです。 I'm not a kind of person who watches TV often.

Related:

- [What does the word「あるほうで」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23883/5010)

Comment: I'm I right that in this case なんで is contracted form of なので for and mean "because; as; since"?

Comment: @sklott Yes it's なので, but here it's just a mild [explanation marker](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/), "..., you know".

Answer (score 0):

方(ほう) is used to make comparisons.

用心深いほう means "the more cautious one".

Examples from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%96%B9/#je-68957):

> 4 〔比べられる物の一方〕a side; a part
>
> その小さい方をください
>   Give me the smaller one.
>
> 私の方の手落ちでした
>   The fault was mine.
>
> 彼の方に不服はなかった
>   There was no dissatisfaction on his part.
>
> 私たちは皆彼の方についた
>   All of us sided with him.
>
> 生活は今の方が前より楽だ
>   I am better off than I used to be.

and from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/200925/meaning/m1u/%E6%96%B9/):

> ３ 二つ以上あるもののうちの一つをとりあげてさす語。
>   「黒い方が好きだ」
>   「もっと味を濃くした方がいい」
>   「こちらの方が悪かった」

Comment: どこからどこまでが引用ですか？　例文と英訳（（以下同文

Comment: `用心深いほう means "the more cautious one".` <-- Nope! It's [not #4 but #3 on プログレッシブ和英](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%96%B9/#je-68957) 「3 〔部類〕
彼は勉強家の方だ
He is rather studious.／He's on the studious side.」 and [not #3 but #4 on デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/200925/meaning/m1u/) 「４ どちらかといえばこちらだという部類。「性質は臆病な方だ」」