# meaning of 方かしら( possible duplicate)

Tags: grammar

I am looking for the meaning of 方かしら

I am aware that かしら has a meaning of "I wonder"

The question may (or not) has been in the post:

[Meaning of ほうなんで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61945/meaning-of-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7)

> この街に来るって事は、冒険者を目指している**方かしら**
>
> If you've come to this town, you must be looking to become adventurers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

方【かた】 is a noun which is a respectful way to say "person". So 「冒険者を目指している方」would simply mean "Someone/people who are aiming to become adventurers."

This is the second definition for 方 on [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%B9) and the fourth definition on [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%96%B9-442815). It is pronounced かた.